# Javascript "push" into array not working (Facebook app)

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, push

I am trying to store my friends list (name, picture and gender) on a var, but it doesn't work correctly. Please ready the comments in the code for the details. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
function getFriendsArray() {    
    var friendsArray = [];
        FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,picture,gender', function(response) {
      if(response.data) {
        var data = '';
        $.each(response.data, function(indice, item) {
            alert(item.name); // Friend's name are displayed correctly
            friendsArray.push(item); // I believe this doesn't work
        });                       
      }
      else {
          errorHandler('getFriendsArray', JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    });

alert(friendsArray.length); // Returns 0 (incorrect)

return friendsArray.sort(sortByName);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `function(response)` is asynchronous. You should insert the alert after `$.each`

for completeness: you should change your approach to problem: do not call a function that returns an Array but that call a second function.

```
function getFriendsArray(callback, errorHandler) {    
    var friendsArray = [];
        FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,picture,gender', function(response) {
      if(response.data) {
        var data = '';
        $.each(response.data, function(indice, item) {
            alert(item.name); // Friend's name are displayed correctly
            friendsArray.push(item); // I believe this doesn't work
        });
        callback(friendsArray);                       
      }
      else {
          errorHandler('getFriendsArray', JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    });
}

getFriendsArray(function(friends) {
    alert(friends);
},
function(error) {
    alert('error');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The first alert is working (obviously), but the second one (which is after the $.each) is not. The real problem is that I am returning an empty array.

Comment: the second cannot works. You should call a second function for continue your algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the FB.api makes an asynchronous request (like jQuery.ajax) and so you are executing `alert(friendsArray.length)` before the FB.api call completes and pushes the results into the friends array.

Comment: Thanks. So what can I do to return the array with the right values? Make it syncronous? THanks